# ORA-00161: transaction branch length 103 is illegal (maximum allowed 64

Tags: c#, oracle

Error:

```
ORA-00161: transaction branch length 103 is illegal (maximum allowed 64…
```

I'm using the DAC from Oracle, any idea if there is a patch for this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a similar issue for .net 2.0, vista and oracle http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=516250